# Send Array of Request Body in an Alamofire Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to send an array of request body and following is the request body that i have to send

```
[{
   "user": "abc",
   "id": "demo"
}]
```

**What i've tried?**

```
var requestArray = [[String: String]]()
let params = [
            "user": "abc",
            "id": "demo"
        ]
requestArray.append(params)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: myUrl)!)
request.httpMethod = ".post"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestArray)

Alamofire.request(request)
         .response{ 
             response in
             print("Request Body:- \(response.request)")
             print(response)
}
```

**Problems that i am facing**

URL works flawlessly in both Postman and an Android App

Above solution is not working for me. My web service returns me `400 error code (Bad Request)`

I am new to iOS development so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to check your request through postman ?

Comment: yeah i checked my request through postman and it is working fine

Comment: @GaneshKalal Try once  removing `.` from `httpMethod` set with just "post"

Comment: Maybe the `.post` is wrong, try `POST` all caps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys i have fixed the issue. I was playing around with some of the solutions from you guys and suddenly it worked!

**So what was the main problem?**

- I changed the `request.httpMethod = ".post"` to `request.httpMethod = "post"`.

Initially this did not work when i commented back to @NiravD but after some time when i did the changes below, i was able to see the output

**Additional changes to view the response on console**

- Replaced `.response` to `.responseJSON`

Thanks a lot to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Alamofire` requires `Parameter` to be of type `[String: Any]`, and the second you don't need to make a post request like that. No need for  `JSONSerialization`. Try this and it will be ok.

```
  let params: [String: Any] = [
                "user": "abc",
                "id": "demo"
            ]


            Alamofire.request(URL.init(string: myUrl)!, method: .post, parameters: params)
                .validate()
                .responseString {
                    (response) in
                     print(response)
            }
```

Comment: I have tested it on postman and in android app. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

// this should accompaign your required work `[[String:Any]]`

```
var requestArray = [AnyObject] // => Array to conatin dictionaries of type [String: Any]
var dictionaryObject = [String: AnyObject] // => to create some dictionary to append in requestArray
dictionaryObject["user"] = "abc"
dictionaryObject["id"] = "demo"
requestArray.append(dictionaryObject)

Alamofire.request(URL.init(string: myUrl)!, method: .post, parameters: requestArray).validate().responseString { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing headers. Can you try it adding the headers that you can see n postman?

Comment: Check the code once again. I have specified the headers

Comment: Sorry i missed it. But may be you can try it with adding like this:
let headers: HttpHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

Answer (score -2):

You must pass your requestArray from Alamofire.request instead of  request

```
Alamofire.request(requestArray)
manager.request(url, method: .get, headers: AUTH_HEADER).responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {
        case .success:
            //whatever you want to do in succes

        case .failure(let error):
            if let del = self.delegate {
                //do what you want
            }
            print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question properly before giving answer. And also requestArray cannot be passed to `Alamofire.request`